# Screen goes black during call

Tags: calls, 9.0-pie

Often, when I try make a call or use the phone app on my phone, the screen goes black.  I have a Pixel 1 with Android version 9.  This is a problem because I can't see or use the numbers or buttons on the screen!  What is the fix?